# Dictionary for traditional characters

Tags: dictionary

I want to start learning traditional characters， but I don't know any good dictionaries that shows the strokes and maybe the meaning of each particular character.

Can you recommend a good dictionary? (I know that PLECO shows traditional characters but I would be interested in one that is devoted to traditional characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the 國語辭典, 國語辭典簡編本, or 國語小字典; depends on your level.

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm

http://dict.concised.moe.edu.tw/jbdic/search.htm

http://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gdic/gsweb.cgi?o=ddictionary

these are authoritative and free :)

for stroke order, try this one:

https://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/home.do

welcome onboard

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!